# Why is my checkbox not visible?

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm developing an application with [Extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api). I define a [checkbox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox) as follow:

```
{
   xtype: 'checkboxfield',
   fieldLabel: 'This is a CHECKBOX, but it\'s  not display',
   style: {
      width: '95%',
      marginBottom: '10px',
      color: 'blue'
   },
}
```

My form with checkbox:
[image]
It display the `fieldLabel`, but don't show the `checkbox`. When I define `change` listeners, and then I press `tab` key, and then press `space`key, `change` listeners fires.

**Where is the problem**?
I set styles, But it change nothing. **What am I doing wrong**?

Comment: Could you provide a total example on the fiddle, it is definitely a problem of layout, but it is hard to say what is wrong only by checkbox config.

Comment: On which device or browser are you testing? Also please post complete form panel code so that we can check and let you know because you have posted only checkbox field code and that is fine.

Comment: Google Chrome Desktop. Windows 7.

Comment: add a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com). I guess the checkbox is hidden because lack of space in the form

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{
     xtype: 'checkboxfield',
     fieldLabel: 'checkboxlabel',
     id:'checkboxid',
     minWidth: 50,
     padding: 0,
     allowBlank: true,
     labelSeparator: '',
     listeners: {
        labelEl: {
            click: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
     }
}
```